# Tenacious, what am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Wrapped around and around
> My good friend that spins in bounds
> Without me, he'll be removed
> By another with me on the groove
> I'm quite tenacious, yes I am
> Clinging on while I still can
> I keep many people safe
> Unless on wet or icy ways

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I've taken this too literally, but:

> Rubber

Wrapped around and around

> Rubber is wrapped around a tire

My good friend that spins in bounds

> The tire is a "friend" of rubber and spins

Without me, he'll be removed

> Tires with the rubber worn out are dangerous/useless and removed from the car

By another with me on the groove

> Not quite sure about this one, either the rubber is attached to some groove on the rim of the tire or this is referring to the grooves on the surface of the rubber?

I'm quite tenacious, yes I am

> It takes a long time to wear out the rubber on a tire

Clinging on while I still can

> Same as above

I keep many people safe

> Increases friction; gives people more control over their vehicle

Unless on wet or icy ways

> Rubber/tires can slide on wet/icy roads

Comment: You're on the right track! Think more specifically, though; what exactly is this thing that's made of rubber?

Comment: Maybe you're hinting at rot13(cebsvyr)?

Comment: I think you got it already: rot13(gur jbeq gb svaq vf "gler" naq gur tbbq sevraq vf gur jurry vgfrys, be vgf uho)